Issues saving pcolormesh in loop
I'm trying to save many images containing a matplotlib pcolormesh in a loop with the following code :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

time_axis = np.arange(0, 30 + 1 / 50, 1 / 50)
another_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 1)

grid = np.zeros((len(another_axis), len(time_axis)))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(2):
    grid = np.random.random((len(another_axis), len(time_axis)))
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(time_axis, another_axis, grid)
    fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax)
    fig.savefig(f"test{i}.png")
    plt.clf()

But my second plot always looks like the attached (2nd) image. I can't tell if this is an issue with pcolormesh or the colorbar etc. Maybe it's the plt.clf()? I'm using that I think it lines up with the ideas in this answer.
EDIT: Trying with ax.clear() at the end means the second plot has two colorbars.



The problem you are having is that when you call plt.clf(), it removes everything from the plot, including the Axes instance ax. So when you use ax.pcolormesh in the next iteration, that is trying to place the pcolormesh on an Axes instance which is no longer displayed on this figure.
One solution would be to recreate the ax each time in the loop. You can do this with ax = fig.add_subplot(), but then when you create the figure, we don't want to also create ax, so we would change that from plt.subplots()  to plt.figure():
fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(2):
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    grid = np.random.random((len(another_axis), len(time_axis)))
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(time_axis, another_axis, grid)
    fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax)
    fig.savefig(f"test{i}.png")
    fig.clf()


Another solution would be to keep the existing ax and use ax.cla() in your loop, rather the fig.clf(). The removes the need to recreate it each time. We can also then reuse the existing Colorbar, rather than recreating that each time, by updating the limits using the Colorbar.update_normal method.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cbar = None

for i in range(2):
    grid = np.random.random((len(another_axis), len(time_axis)))
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(time_axis, another_axis, grid)
    if cbar is None:
        cbar = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax)
    else:
        cbar.update_normal(pcm)
    fig.savefig(f"test{i}.png")
    ax.cla()

If, however, you know the limits on your Colorbar will never change, you might consider fixing them when you make the pcolormesh (I do that here with vmin=0, vmax=1), and then leaving the Colorbar you create in the first iteration without having to update it every time you update the pcolormesh:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
cbar = None

for i in range(2):
    grid = np.random.random((len(another_axis), len(time_axis)))
    pcm = ax.pcolormesh(time_axis, another_axis, grid, vmin=0, vmax=1)
    if cbar is None:
        cbar = fig.colorbar(pcm, ax=ax)
    fig.savefig(f"test{i}.png")
    ax.cla()


great answer, thank you!
